# How to add a custom field for a product details page for Hikashop?

Tags: joomla-3.x, hikashop

I have just started using Hikashop for ecommerce and followed the directions from this link: https://www.hikashop.com/support/documentation/42-hikashop-field-form.html

My problem is that I can't get the `table` column in my admin.
[image]

I have this:

[image]

Please help me to insert the column.

Answer (score 1):

It is available in the paid version. But it should be in the Free version. If anyone need this in the free version, please comment on this.

Comment: Is this an extension on the question? I am not sure if this is an "answer".  Do you still need support or are you offering to help someone if they leave you a comment?

Comment: Yes, i know and now i am creating a plugin for that. So that one can create a custom field in the free version also.

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert that column from the database table schema (hikashop insert custom column directly from the table definition, too), and override the hikashop view to show that column from your overrided layout, if you know Joomla override template well and how to fix the php code :)

Comment: Let's assume that the OP and future researchers will not have the base knowledge to execute your advice.  Can you describe your proposed solution with greater detail/generosity?